# Static linking library asan with gcc 4.8

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-errors, gcc4.8, address-sanitizer

I'm compiling my test executable in this way using gcc 4.8.3:

```
gcc -o test -g -L/lib64 -fsanitize=address -static-libasan
```

Result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Libasan is installed and if I compile without the static option it works. How can I compile the library statically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install special package to get static GCC libraries. On Ubuntu you should do

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgcc-4.8-dev
```